# How to create a JSON object with nested object and array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

This is what I want my object to look like:

```
{
    "cluster": "testcluster",
    "instance": "i-03f8f8c9e7febab21",
    "instype": "r4.8xlarge",
    "AZ": "us-east-1e",
    "env": "test", 
    "cpus":  "32",
    "memory": "256G",
    "kernel": "4.4.0-96-generic",
    "info": "cpu usage stats",
    "unit": "percent",
    "cpustats": [
          {"metric":"user", "values":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]},
          {"metric":"sys",  "values":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]},
          {"metric":"idle", "values":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]},
          {"metric":"softirq", "values":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]},
          {"metric":"intr", "values":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]},
          {"metric":"steal", "values":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]},
          {"metric":"user", "values":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]}
   ]
}
```

How to build in php?

Comment: show your code first. we're not code generators.

Comment: This is your new best friend [json formatter + validation](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Step 1: Do a bunch of research. Step 2: Try something. Step 3: If you get stuck on something _specific_ which you just can't find the solution for online, come back and show us what you've tried, where you're stuck, expected output and the actual output and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry man, but the question is explained really bad!! If I understand, You want a JSON like above (Your post)

> PHP has a particular functions to manage JSON Object : json_encode AND json_decode

---

## Using json_encode

It is used to convert an Object into JSON String

```
<?php
/** You can also use Arrays (Ex. $myArray = array(...)) */
$myObject = new StdClass();

$myObject->newKey = "newValue";
$myObject->otherKey = "otherValue";

$myObject->nestedArrays = array(
    'array1' => array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2', 
        /** ... OTHER KEY-VALUE ... */
        'keyN' => 'vakyeN'
    ),

    'array2' => array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2', 
        /** ... OTHER KEY-VALUE ... */
        'keyN' => 'vakyeN'
    )
);

/** ... OTHER CODE ... */

$myJSONString = json_encode($myObject);

print_r($myJSONString);

/** OUTPUT
  * {
  *     "newKey":"newValue",
  *     "otherKey":"otherValue",
  *     "nestedArrays":{
  *         "array1":{
  *             "key1":"value1",
  *             "key2":"value2",
  *             "keyN":"vakyeN"
  *         },
  *         "array2":{
  *             "key1":"value1",
  *             "key2":"value2",
  *             "keyN":"vakyeN"
  *         }
  *     }
  * }
  */

?>
```

---

## Using json_decode

It is used to retrieve the original Object from a JSON String

```
<?php

$myObject = json_decode($myJSONString);

?>
```

---

## Now try to create JSON String of Your post =)

#### My attempt using your idea:

I changed how the JSON should look like:

```
{
    "cluster": "testcluster",
    "instance": "i-03f8f8c9e7febab21",
    "instype": "r4.8xlarge",
    "AZ": "us-east-1e",
    "env": "test", 
    "cpus":  "32",
    "memory": "256G",
    "kernel": "4.4.0-96-generic",
    "info": "cpu usage stats",
    "unit": "percent",
    "cpustats": {
          "user":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891],
          "sys":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891],
          "idle":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891],
          "softirq":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891],
          "intr":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891],
          "steal":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883,1889,1891]
    }
}
```

#### code:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->cluster="testcluster";
$obj->instance="i-03f8f8c9e7febab21";
$obj->instype="r4.8xlarge";
$obj->AZ="us-east-1e",
$obj->env="test",
$obj->cpus="32";
$obj->memory="25G";
$obj->kernelversion="4.4.0-96-generic";
$obj->info="cpu usage stats";
$obj->unit="percent";
$obj->cpustats = new stdClass();
$obj->cpustats->usr = array(1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883); 
$obj->cpustats->sys = array(1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883); 
$obj->cpustats->idle = array(1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883); 
$obj->cpustats->softirq = array(1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883); 
$obj->cpustats->intr = array (1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883); 
$obj->cpustats->steal = array (1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883); 

var_dump(json_encode($obj));
```

#### Output:

```
string(555) "{
"cluster":"testcluster",
"instance":"i-03f8f8c9e7febab21",
"instype":"r4.8xlarge",
"AZ":"us-east1e",
"env":"test",
"cpus":"32",
"memory":"25G",
"kernelversion":"4.4.0-96-generic",
"info":"cpu usage stats",
"unit":"percent",
"cpustats":{
"usr":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883],
"sys":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883],
"idle":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883],
"softirq":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883],
"intr":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883],
"steal":[1874,1857,1884,1869,1909,1912,1901,1880,1883]
}"
```